# C#: How do i get 2 lists into one 2-tuple list in

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I have 2 Lists. First one is Type `string`. The second is type `object`. Now I want to get both lists into a `Tuple<string,object>`. 
like this

```
var List = new(string list1, object list2)[]
```

How do I do this?

I had to create 2 seperate lists, because I am Serializing the object and the serializing wouldn't work if i had a `List<Tuple<string,object>>` in the first place.
 Both lists can get big so maybe with foreach loop?

Comment: `(string list1, object list2)` is a ValueTuple struct, not a Tuple class. If you want value tuples (which I would recommend due to the tuple components being properly named) just replace `new Tuple<string, object>(x, y)` or `Tuple.Create(a, b)` in the answers by `(x, y)`  or `(a, b)`, respectively.

Comment: can you show me an example please?

Comment: If you take Markus answer just replace the last line with `List<(string yourFieldNameHere1, object yourFieldNameHere)> result = lst.Zip(obj, (x, y) => (x, y)).ToList();`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.7.2) method to create one list of the two:

```
var lst = new List<string>() { "a", "b" };
var obj = new List<object>() { 1, 2 };
var result = lst.Zip(obj, (x, y) => new Tuple<string, object>(x, y))
                .ToList();
```

Comment: This will merge two list. Is it OP's expected behavior? Not sure form his question.

Comment: @TanvirArjel from the title: "How do I get two lists into one..."; I suspect the pseudo-code in the question is a bit misleading.

Comment: Yes! Your are correct what you have understood! it can also be he is trying pass two list as tuple like (list1,list2). But using Zip do parallel looping through the items, not serially.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Linq [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) method:

```
List<string> list1 = GetStrings();
List<object> list2 = GetObjects();

var merged = list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => Tuple.Create(a, b));
```